# Ad hoc distribution: App failed to install

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, distribution, adhoc

I have created an ad hoc archive and a .ipa file for the application I am trying to distribute.  I have also created a distributing provisioning profile with the UDIDs of the devices that I plan on distributing my application to.  When I drag the .ipa and .mobileprovision files into iTunes and try to sync the application to the device, an error message on the phone pops up reading "'myapp' failed to install". By the way, I have a standard iOS developer's license ($99 per year) and am using Xcode version 4.2.1.  I am pretty new to the developer program, so please try to keep your answers as simple as possible.  Let me know if you need any extra information.  Thank you!

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715253/adhoc-app-installation-failed-in-iphone-why and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931387/why-does-an-ad-hoc-ipa-fail-to-install-on-one-device-yet-succeed-on-another-wit and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295890/iphone-ad-hoc-build-using-xcode-4

Answer (score 22):

I had the exact same issue.  My issue was simple to fix.  Check your Code Signing Identities for Project & Target in your project Build Settings.  Mine were pointing to my Development Profile.

The Code Signing Identities need to point to the Ad hoc Distribution Profile that you created.
Make this change and then recreate the Archive and .ipa file.  I then deleted the old App in iTunes, and then dragged the .ipa file onto the iTunes icon (Windows).  Then I was able to use iTunes to install the App successfully.

Comment: Holy crap they changed the default order od Development and Distribution: When I make the archive than at the Office need to select the second one from list to sign: Distribution, at home ( now ) it is the Development at the second position, which can't be installed via iTunes :)

Comment: I've created my Ad hoc Distribution Profile, downloaded and double clicked it. The distribution provisioning profile is now listed in the Organizer in XCode. However, it's status is "Valid signing identity not found". I think this is why I can't find it when I edit the Code Signing Identities as you've suggested. How can I solve this?

Comment: @grautzen the best solution for me was to go back online (developer.apple.com) delete all provisioning profiles and certificates and generate them from scratch (first xcode will create certificates, then online you create the provisioning profiles).

Answer (score 2):

My problem seemed to be Xcode.  I had multiple copies of the Ad_Hoc profile with different expirations (all valid) and a few with different names from the days.  I deleted them all and the app still failed to install, but I noticed all the Ad_Hoc profiles had been resurrected by iTunes.  Tried it several times and including deleting them from the Organizer, but they always resurrected (reappeared installed on the device). Finally I drug out a copy of the supposedly extinct iPhone Configuration utility and used it to delete the app and all Ad_Hoc profiles.  Then tried to install just the profile.  That got it down to 2.  Finally got all deleted and got iTunes to install the right profile.  Still took 2 more attempts for iTunes to finally install my archive file!

Answer (score 1):

Check this .

Don't need to drag both .ipa and Provisioning Profile.

Just Drag the .IPA File Follow Further steps as you.

Comment: Does checking or unchecking the "Save for Enterprise" box change anything?

Comment: this step will generate a separate .xml file which is required to distribute application ipa over the air (OTA).... @bgottlob

Answer (score 1):

Set install owner param in Xcode project / Deployment to the name you specified in apple dev license. I set both install owner and alternative install owner and Install Group and Alternative Install Group to my name which the 100% exactly as in my apple development license.
And the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where my project was stored on a secondary NTFS drive. After moving the project over to my desktop [aka MacOS Extended (Journaled) drive], I was able to load the ipa file via itunes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by not trying to sync with iTunes but instead to sync it within Xcode (from the window->devices menu)

Answer (score 0):

Another point: If the store version of the app installed on your device (or a version deployed another provision), you have to remove it from your device before installing the ad-hoc version.